# Automate scheduled extraction of Bloomberg data from text files, load into database, and access data from within Excel (similar to BB desktop API)

Tags: c#, etl, bloomberg, excel-dna

At present we access Bloomberg data using their Excel Add-in. This has allowed us to embed BB functions (e.g. BDP, BDH) directly into our Excel/VBA-based analyses, and import/refresh data as necessary.

We are now required to move to a new data delivery format. Namely, text files representing the entire universe of securities we cover, which are made available on BB servers on a daily basis at a scheduled time.

We would like to transition to this new format with only minor, or at least limited, changes to our Excel formulas.

Consequently we need to develop an automated method for the scheduled extraction of data from text files, data storage in an appropriate database, and a method to access data from this database from within Excel.

There appear to be a plethora of different solutions to this problem, some simple, some less so, using a variety of tools, requiring varying levels of programming and development.

For example, it has been suggested that a simple C# script can undertake the ETL portion of the work. We could then use Excel-DNA to develop a native Excel add-in to implement functions similar to BDP/BDH which pull data from the database.

Before we go down this route however any thoughts as to a simple solution which we may not have considered would be greatly appreciated. We have little experience of data modelling so specifics with regard to applications/platforms/programming languages would be useful.

Comment: This probably is outside of scope of SO - designing systems of any size is unlikely to lead to concrete answers to concrete coding problem.

Comment: In which case can you recommend an appropriate forum for this kind of query?

Answer (score 0):

It is a conceptual thing that you have going on, but to maintain the status quo, you're looking replicate the BDP / BDH functionality.

As long as you take in the data during the ETL process with the same field names as the Bloomberg data, then really the custom addin can work in the same was as BDP that is `=BDP(Security, Field)`

Do you use any of the overrides when you request data? As you'll also need to think about this.

Personally, working on something similar we've taken the approach to move as much work to the database as possible, and output specific datasets to Excel. This does require a re-engineering of your current setup but this if often beneficial (and can be sold as such) as a means to streamline this process.

You could look at using something like SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) for your ETL into the database. Downstream to Excel / Other Applications, the world is your oyster.